# Why does it skip the If statement inside the While loop? It prints out "no work", why?

Tags: java

This is the program

```
import java.util.Scanner; //imports class

public class blank2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     boolean valid = true;
     String ans;
     ans = in.next(); //answer is a string
```

If you type in "y", it goes right to the else statement.

```
while (valid == true)
{
```

it always skips this statement

```
    if (ans == "y")
    {
       System.out.println("it works");
       valid = false;
    {
    else
    {   
       System.out.println("no work");
       valid = false;
    {   
}   


   }

}
```

It just wont work

Answer (score 6):

```
 if (ans == "y")
```

Don't compare strings with `==`. That compares object references(the same string). Use:

```
 if ("y".equals(answer))
```

instead. It will compare strings for equality(check if they are identical as opposed to the same one). I do not use `answer.equals("y")` due to the risk of a null pointer exception if `answer` was null for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

In strings, don't use the ==, you can use `compareTo` instead.

```
  if ("y".comprateTo(answer))
```

With this method you can check if they are the same, or if one is greater than the other.

let us know if you have questions

Comment: The code produces a type mismatch. You could use `if ("y".comprateTo(answer)==0)` but `if ("y".equals(answer))` is more intuitive and probably faster.

Comment: yes, it's true. the `equals` was already here, I just gave @user2892492 other options to the future.

Comment: @X-Pippes I would argue that compareTo isn't of very much use until one starts sorting.